# How can we create separate excel sheets using python pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, automation

For ex: I have one excel file as my input, consisting of 50K records of employees.
Employees are working in different companies A,B, and C.

How can we filter this input excel file on the basis of companies and create new output Excel file.
Which consist of separate sheets For Companies A,B, and C.

In output excel file Sheet A should have only employees working in A company.
Sheet B should have only employees working in B company.
Sheet C should have only employees working in C company.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
df=pd.read_excel('your_main_file.xlsx')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
for i in set(df['Company']):
    temp = df[df.Company == i]
    temp.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Company_'+str(i))

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: I believe he needs one excel file with multiple sheets, which you can add as a second argument to the to_excel.

Comment: Thanks for you help. But I want one excel file with multiple sheets, as Mentioned by @Mohammad

Comment: @AbhishekChoubey the updated code does that indeed

Comment: df=pd.read_excel('your_main_file.xlsx')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
for i in set(df['Company']):
    temp = df[df.Company == i]
    temp.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Company_'+str(i))

writer.save()
writer.close()  


@IoaTzimas Thank you very much this code works as my requirements.